# Flutter How to set cloud front cookie in expo video player plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming

Am facing problem in setting DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory in expo player using flutter video player plugin.

Actually am playing HLS video from CDN for to make secure playing i created CloudFront Signature keys to that video file.

I have set properties of cloudfront cookie key and values to expo player but its not playing.

In File :
**android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/VideoPlayer.java**

```
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ExoPlayer", null, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
httpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("CloudFront-Policy","eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOkZnJvbnQubmV0LyoiLCJDb2MjA3MDAxOTh9fX1dfQ__");
httpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("CloudFront-Signature","j0c8xdJqLEeF9xCRd4C~-9-J3KLA6vsLMZf-wfvSXtKhDatr3hXDCZ4yjIedlRs-7qTFTeVzKeg9lG0D0VROjzx1aMUe3NsphOPBOZJduw7mULOwS-OeTvd3AtGeU7du0B4LFN-utVntooBwSFesthLQ__");
httpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id","AHJKAINYJDNGHTDX7V5BA");
dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "ExoPlayer",httpDataSourceFactory);
```

Error throwing in console like :

```
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403, null)
```

so , help me on this how to set and play the video by signed cookie

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Hi i got solution very long back but forgot to post answer.

Here is my workaround for the problem,

When we pass multiple cookie header, cloudfront will replace each one and take last one.

```
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ExoPlayer", null, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
httpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("CloudFront-Policy","MDAxOTh9fX1dfQ__");
httpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("CloudFront-Signature","LFN-utVntooBwSFesthLQ__");
httpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id","V5BA");
dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "ExoPlayer",httpDataSourceFactory);
```

Solution is to set as single value by appending cookies seperate with semicolon

```
String cookieValue = "";
if(CloudFrontPolicy != null && CloudFrontSignature !=null && CloudFrontKeyPairId != null){
    cookieValue +="CloudFront-Policy="+CloudFrontPolicy+";";
    cookieValue +="CloudFront-Signature="+CloudFrontSignature+";";
    cookieValue +="CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id="+CloudFrontKeyPairId+";";
}

DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory defaultHttpDataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                        "ExoPlayer",
                        null,
                        DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                        DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                        true);
defaultHttpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("Cookie",cookieValue);
dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, null, defaultHttpDataSourceFactory);
defaultHttpDataSourceFactory.createDataSource();
```